# Social Security Number Validation That Accepts Dashes, Spaces or No Spaces

Tags: regex

Social Security numbers that I want to accept are:

```
xxx-xx-xxxx (ex. 123-45-6789)
xxxxxxxxx (ex. 123456789)
xxx xx xxxx (ex. 123 45 6789)
```

I am not a regex expert, but I wrote this (it's kind of ugly)

```
^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(\d{3}\d{2}\d{4})|(\d{3}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{4})$
```

However this social security number passes, when it should actually fail since there is only one space

```
12345 6789
```

So I need an updated regex that rejects things like

```
12345 6789
123 456789
```

To make things more complex it seems that SSNs cannot start with 000 or 666 and can go up to 899, the second and third set of numbers also cannot be all 0.

I came up with this

```
^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}[ \-](?!00)[0-9]{2}[ \-](?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

Which validates with spaces or dashes, but it fails if the number is like so

```
123456789
```

Ideally these set of SSNs should pass

```
123456789
123 45 6789
123-45-6789
899-45-6789
001-23-4567
```

And these should fail

```
12345 6789
123 456789
123x45x6789
ABCDEEEEE
1234567890123
000-45-6789
123-00-6789
123-45-0000
666-45-6789
```

Comment: To answer your question about why `12345 6789` matches, I see that your regex is in the form of `^(this)|(that)|(theother)$`. You may be having a problem here in that `^` and `$` are actually *atoms*, and what your expression is saying is "permit `^this` or `that` or `theother$`. What you want is `^(this|that|theother)$`. Think of the or-bars as having higher precedence than the null anchors at the start and end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your problem with dashes, spaces, etc. being consistent, you can use a backreference. Make the first separator a group and allow it to be optional  - `([ \-]?)`. You can then reference it with `\1` to make sure the second separator is the same as the first one:

```
^(?!000|666)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\1(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/1) (thanks @Tushar)

Comment: [`^(?!000|666)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\1(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/1)

Comment: That definitely did it. Thanks @Szymon.

Comment: Also @Tushar you did not use [ /-] and used [ -] which makes it a bit cleaner, since in Java I have to escape all \.

Answer (score 10):

More complete validation rules are available on CodeProject at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651609/Validating-Social-Security-Numbers-through-Regular. Copying the information here in case the link goes away, but also expanding on the codeproject answer a bit.

A Social Security number CANNOT :

- Contain all zeroes in any specific group (ie 000-##-####, ###-00-####, or ###-##-0000)
- Begin with ’666′.
- Begin with any value from ’900-999′
- Be ’078-05-1120′  (due to the Woolworth’s Wallet Fiasco)
- Be ’219-09-9999′ (appeared in an advertisement for the Social Security Administration)

This RegEx taken from the referenced CodeProject article will validate all Social Security numbers according to all the rules - requires dashes as separators.

```
^(?!219-09-9999|078-05-1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$
```

Same with spaces, instead of dashes

```
^(?!219 09 9999|078 05 1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3} (?!00)\d{2} (?!0{4})\d{4}$
```

Finally, this will validate numbers without spaces or dashes

```
^(?!219099999|078051120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0{4})\d{4}$
```

Combining the three cases above, we get the

#### Answer

```
^((?!219-09-9999|078-05-1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4})|((?!219 09 9999|078 05 1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3} (?!00)\d{2} (?!0{4})\d{4})|((?!219099999|078051120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0{4})\d{4})$
```

Comment: Using the above validates with 111111111 or 222222222 and so on. Surely these are not valid ssn numbers ?

Comment: I would hope numbers like 111111111 or 222222222 were not actually issued to anybody. But we are not trying to find out whether a given number was issued to real person, just whether it meets the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement to validate SSN's. This regex will validate SSN for below rules

1. Matches dashes, spaces or no spaces
2. Numbers, 9 digits, non-alphanumeric
3. Exclude all zeros
4. Exclude beginning characters `666,000,900,999,123456789,111111111,222222222,333333333,444444444,555555555,666666666,777777777,888888888,999999999`
5. Exclude ending characters `0000`

   ```
   ^(?!123([ -]?)45([ -]?)6789)(?!\b(\d)\3+\b)(?!000|666|900|999)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\4(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
   ```

Explanation

```
     ^ - Beginning of string  
    (?!123([ -]?)45([ -]?)6789) - Don't match 123456789, 123-45-6789, 123 45 6789  
    (?!\b(\d)\3+\b) - Don't match 00000000,111111111...999999999. Repeat same with space and dashes. '\3' is for backtracking to (\d)  
    (?!000|666|900|999) - Don't match SSN that begins with 000,666,900 or 999.
    ([ -]?) - Check for space and dash. '?' is used to make space and dash optional. ? is 0 or 1 occurence of previous character.
    (?!00) - the 4th and 5th characters cannot be 00.
    \4 - Backtracking to check for space and dash again after the 5th character. 
    (?!0000) - The last 4 characters cannot be all zeros.
    $ - End of string
    Backtracking is used to repeat a captured group (). Each group is represented sequentially 1,2,3..so on
```

See here for more explanation and examples
https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/3